# Unable to debug in jsp anymore

Tags: jsp, debugging, myeclipse

I was able to always debug in jsp files no problem. But I made some code changes and during my testing the points will no longer hit where I placed them, only my class files. I noticed the blue marks in the jsp file were did not have ticks were as the class file did. Reading stuff online said this is cause the byte code and source code are not in sync. I have redeployed and restarted with neither having an effect. I was just debugging this with no issue till I made changes, has anyone encountered this?

Comment: JSP is the View part of the Model-View-Controller paradigm and should thus contain only tags and EL, not the business (debuggable) code. Such code belongs to controller, i.e. servlet.

Comment: @JozefChocholacek True... but this doesn't answer my question. JSP pages can contain java and should not but unfortunately for me there are some really old jsp pages with java code that I gotta leave as is for now and just work with it. When changes need to be done I am able to make my changes and debug them within JSP no problem but just recently I have been unable to debug the pages.

Comment: @testItAll you tagged this post, "MyEclipse", can you tell me what version of MyEclipse you are using, also , what server your are deploying to, so we can assist further?

Comment: @BrianFernandes well it started working for other jsp pages i just had to update and make changes, haven't been able to go back the the one i had issues with. I did not make any changes to my setting. My guess is my env was acting up maybe. I am on my eclipse Version: 2017 CI 9 and I am deploying to tomcat 7

Comment: @testItAll yes, this sounds very much like an environmental issue. We're here if you need further assistance.